# Highcharts getjson and changing series type dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I wan't to change series type, but
 there is an javascript console error:
 options.series in function change_chart is null...

```
<script src="../code/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var options;

$(document).ready(function() {
    options = {
        chart: { renderTo: 'container'},
        rangeSelector: {selected: 1},
        title: { text: 'AAPL Stock Price'},

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price11',
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [
                    [
                        'week', // unit name
                        [1] // allowed multiples
                    ], [
                        'month',
                        [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }]    
    };

    chartfunc = function(type)
    {
        alert(options.series);      
        options.type = type;
        chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options);
    }

    $.getJSON('http://localhost/highstock/data/aapl-ohlcv.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options);
    });
});     
        </script>
```

I don't understand why options.series "sets itself" to null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing chartfunc like this:

```
chartfunc = function(type)
{
    chart.series[0].update({
        type: type
    });
}
```